# How to get Data from MongoDb using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I just started learning MongoDB and mongoose. Currently I have the following structure:

```
database   -> skeletonDatabase
collection -> adminLogin
```

When I run `db.adminLogin.find()` from the command line I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52lhafkjasfadsfea"), "username" : "xxxx", "password" : "xxxx" }
```

**My connection** *(this works, just adding it FYI)*

```
module.exports = function(mongoose)
{
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/skeletonDatabase');

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback () {
        console.log('Conntected To Mongo Database');
    });
}
```

**My -js-**

```
module.exports = function(mongoose)
{
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    // login schema
    var adminLogin = new Schema({
        username: String,
        password: String
    });

    var adminLoginModel = mongoose.model('adminLogin', adminLogin);
    var adminLogin = mongoose.model("adminLogin");

    adminLogin.find({}, function(err, data){
        console.log(">>>> " + data );
    });
}
```

My `console.log()` returns as `>>>>`

So what am I doing wrong here? Why do I not get any data in my console log? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

mongoose by default takes singular model names and pairs them with a collection named with the plural of that, so mongoose is looking in the db for a collection called "adminLogins" which doesn't exist. You can specify your collection name as the 2nd argument when defining your schema:

```
var adminLogin = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
}, {collection: 'adminLogin'});
```

Comment: It's a terrible anti-feature. I think I've seen talk on github of putting a stop to it in some future release. If you are using express, `res.send(data)` to send it to the browser and you're done.

Comment: Nice to know, yeah I am using express. But I am a little foggy on that as well. I tried using `res.send(data)` but couldn't quiet figure out how the whole response thing was suppose to work. I have my app.configure global along with my mongoose connection. So I am using `require()` but wasn't sure how to pass a request through it.

Answer (score 2):

Had a problem with injecting it within an express route for my api so I changed it thanks to @elkhrz by first defining the schema and then compiling that one model I want to then pull like so:

```
app.get('/lists/stored-api', (req, res) => {

    Apis.find(function(err, apis) {

        if (err) return console.error(err);

        res.send(apis);

    });

});
```

I wouldn't send it to the body, I would actually do something else with it especially if you plan on making your API a production based application.

Run through this problem and read up on possible proper ways of rendering your data:
[How to Pass Data Between Routes in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796878/how-to-pass-data-between-routes-in-express)

Always a good idea to practice safe procedures when handling data.

Answer (score 1):

first compile just **one** model with the schema as an argument

`var adminLogin = mongoose.model('adminLogin', adminLogin);`

in your code adminLogin does not exist, adminLoginModel does;

after that ,instead to

```
adminLogin.find({}, function(err, data){
        console.log(">>>> " + data );
    });
```

try this

```
adminLogin.find(function (err, adminLogins) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(adminLogins);
```

is important the "s" because mongo use the plural of the model to name the collection, sorry for my english...