# Receiving Data from Mongodb using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Can we retrieve data from Mongodb using Mongoose if data has not been entered using Mogoose. Because data is manually entered in the Mongodb database. Currently I am trying to retrieve data using MongooseModel.findOne() method but its not finding the required data.

My Mongoose Model is this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({    
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},   
    password: {type: String, required: true}
});

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

**Database name:** test-mean

**Collection name:** user

**This is my post route that in which I am using Mongoose to retrieve data.**

```
router.post('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({
              title: 'An error occurred',
              error: err
          });
      }
      if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({
              title: 'User Login failed',
              error: {message: 'Invalid login credentials'}
          });
      }
      if (req.body.password != user.password) {          
          console.log('user password ' + user.password);
          console.log('request body password ' + req.body.password);
          return res.status(401).json({
              title: 'Password Login failed',
              error: {message: 'Invalid login credentials'}
          });
      }
      var token = jwt.sign({user: user}, 'secret', {expiresIn: 7200});
      res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Successfully logged in',
          token: token,
          userId: user._id
      });
  });
});
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please add your schema/model declaration to your question, and also the name of the collection that you want to query. Or look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627631/how-to-get-data-from-mongodb-using-mongoose

Comment: Thanks Robert for your response, I have added my Model declaration and the name of collection to my question. Please help.

Comment: @robertklep waiting for your answer.

Comment: Your question has been closed because it's a duplicate of a previous question. The solution for that question will solve your problem.

Comment: Found the solution. thanks alot